# Sending DATA to Mysql using IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) not a URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build an app that will interact with a database (using MariaDB.) As I am approaching this with the lowest level of experience and knowledge I have decided to install the server on my computer directly and try writing to tables within my database (no intermediate software/webserver.) I have found some sample code to start from for this endeavour but unfortunately its commands require a URL. My server only has an IP address.

My eyes are sore from Google and my ears are sore from Youtube.

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https:SOMEURLHERE.com")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "a=\(Usersub.text!)&b=\(Passsub1.text!)"


    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
}
    task.resume()
```

My database has been set up with a table containing 3 columns (user.id, username and password.) right now I am just trying to get values from the app textfield to the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use `https://someIPaddressHere/` (assuming your server supports SSL). Really though you will want some server-side code if you are going to make this a real app (or just use a platform like Firebase or something)

Comment: Wow..... I'm an idiot...... You most definitely can do that.  Thank you and sorry for wasting your attention.

Comment: Unrelated but don't use all of those `NS` classes. Use `URLRequest`, not `NS[Mutable]URLRequest`. Use `String`, not `NSString`. Use `URL`, not `NSURL`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the input I will give it a shout. Is there a specific reason why I should not? also is there a delegate required for the URL session?